# Android image to belong in what drawable folder?

Tags: android, image, resolution, dpi

I read about dpi and supporting multiple screens in Android and still don't get it :(

Fact: I have a background spalsh image sized **480*800** pixels.

Questions: **In what folder should I put it?** drawable-what?

Side note: I tried putting it in drawable-hdpi, but when I added larger sized images, in drawable-land-xhdpi and drawable-port-xhdpi, Android chose to take the bigger ones instead.
The weird part is that this is tested on a **Nexus S** which has a **480*800** pixel size screen. No reason for Android to use a larger sized image!!!

**Edit**: This is a generic question with a specific example. The generic question: consider you have a set of images with different resolutions, representing the same meaning. They should fill the whole screen. **In what folder do you put each?**

Comment: Thinking about it, how come I couldn't find a recommendation for putting what where? Specifically for background images that take the whole screen!!! Developers can continue from there to calculate other drawable resources, like icons compared to the absolute background image.

Answer (score 0):

hdpi is "high density".  *Generally* that means 480*800.  The virtual screen in this situation would be 320*480.

What I suspect you want to do is put that splash image in drawable-hdpi.  Your phone considers itself an hdpi device, so it will look in that folder first for the named resource.  If it finds it there, it will use it.  If it does not, it will look in other drawable folders.

Chances are, you don't have an xhdpi device.  AFAIK, the only one coming out is the Nexus Galaxy.  Some tablets are POSSIBLY xhdpi, but probably not.  hdpi/xhdpi refer to the density, not the size.

So, put it in drawable-hdpi.  You should test your app on phones like the atrix and bionic, that have higher resolutions, but I think are still hdpi screens.  Your splash probably won't look as good as you'd like it to, but should still function.

Comment: I tested it on the Nexus S, as I wrote, and it did **NOT** work.

Comment: No need for a layout. You have an image with a specific resolution. It should fill the whole screen. What resurce drawable folder does it belong?

Comment: Just trying to focus. Publishing the layout, in my opinion, will diverge from the answer.

Comment: Why would publishing your layout make it harder to understand?

Comment: Because the layout is very basic and the question is generic regardless of the layout. Here it is anyways: <RelativeLayout layout_width="fill_parent" layout_height="fill_parent" background="@drawable/background_image">...</RelativeLayout>